# Warning: Unknown DOM property class. Did you mean className?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've just started exploring React, by adding a component with a simple render function:

```
render() {
  return <div class="myApp"></div>
}
```

When I run the app, I get the following error:

```
Warning: Unknown DOM property class. Did you mean className?
```

I can solve this by changing `class` to `className`.

The question is; does React enforce this convention? Also why do I need to use `className` instead of the conventional `class`? If this is a restriction then is it due to JSX syntax or somewhere else?

Answer (score 216, accepted):

Yes, its a React convention:

> Since JSX is JavaScript, identifiers such as `class` and `for` are
>   discouraged as XML attribute names. Instead, React DOM components
>   expect DOM property names like `className` and `htmlFor`, respectively.

[JSX In Depth](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#html-tags-vs.-react-components).

Comment: I find this terribly unintuitive. I think the parser should know how to switch contexts between the two languages based on context, keep the burden off the programmer and on the tools

Comment: Agreed this should be in the tooling, though `class` is a reserved keyword in pretty much every programming language and its quite easy doing Find `class=`, Replace `className=`

Answer (score 23):

In React.js there is no for and class properties available so we need to use

```
for   --> htmlFor
class --> className
```

Answer (score 17):

Meteor uses babel to transpile ES5 to ES6 (ES2015), so we can deal with it as a normal Node application with babel transpiler added.

You need to add `.babelrc` file to your project's root folder, and add the following items

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "react-html-attrs"
  ]
}
```

And of course, you need to install this plugin using `npm`:

> npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-react-html-attrs

Comment: Thank you, I can fix "Invalid DOM" after install react-facebook-login.

Answer (score 13):

In HTML we use

```
class="navbar"
```

but in React and ReactNative there is no HTML, we use JSX(Javascript XML)
here we use

```
className="navbar"
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't use class for any HTML tag attribute  because JS has another meaning of class. That why you have to use className instead of class.

And also use htmlFor attribute instead of for.

Answer (score 4):

In react 16.13.1 you can use class attribute. It throws a "warning" exception but it don'T stop the execution.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The JSX syntax when compiled using babel, underlying syntax it will use to create the HTML element will be

```
   React.createElement('div', {attributes}, "Hello");
```

If we use the class instead of className, the react will infer it as javascript class instead of html class attribute. [Reason the variable name 'class' is already used in the file to create a javascript class and is reserved for the same purpose]. Which is wrong and compiler does throws the error, since javascript class is not a valid property for html DOM elements.

```
   React.createElement("p", {"class": "header"}, "Hello");
```

Hence it is necessary to use className instead of class.

```
   React.createElement("p", {"className": "header"}, "Hello")
```

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same error when i used the tailwind CSS in the vite + react setup. But I fixed it by

METHOD 1)
CHANGING THE FOLLOWING NAMING CONVENTIONS
class --> className
for   --> htmlFor

METHOD 2)
uninstalling the ESLint Extension from the vs code and the code works fine.

I hope it helps for more clearity read above answers of this thread