# Grab the selected value of a select

Tags: reactjs

I have a select that works fine but I need to capture the value that I am selecting, but it is generating an error `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')`, i have not been able to solve it.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import WindowedSelect from "react-windowed-select";

function App() {
  const [t4t, setUniversidad] = useState([]);
  const [e2, setE2] = useState(null);

  console.log(e2 + " Seleccionado");

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const req = await fetch(
        `https://witalenco.com.co/apiWittytalent/dyc/titulos/carreras.php`
      );
      const getres2 = await req.json();
      console.log({ getres2 });
      setUniversidad(await getres2);
    })();
  }, []);

  // Here is the transformation
  const options = t4t.map((item) => ({
    label: item.carrera,
    value: item.id_titulos
  }));

  const handlecountrye2 = (event) => {
    setE2(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div class="col-12">
        <br />

        <WindowedSelect
          options={options}
          onChange={handlecountrye2}
          value={e2}
          name="e2"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-darkness-9z9cck?file=/src/App.js:0-992

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that this isn't *strictly* "a select", this is specifically `react-windowed-select`.  So if you're following examples used for something like a `<select>` then you may be providing yourself with incorrect information.

If `event.target` is `undefined` then what is `event`?  Logging it to the console reveals the following structure:

```
{label: "ABOGADO (A)", value: "3"}
```

(Which also suggests that it's been given a misleading name.  It's not really an "event", more of a selected option.  I would recommend renaming the variable in that function to something which reflects this.)

As you can see, there is indeed no `target` property there.  So what property do you want to use?  It *looks like* you want to use the whole object:

```
setE2(event);
```

I've forked your sandbox demo to demonstrate: https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-estrela-vkf3g2?file=/src/App.js

(Additionally I modified the top-level `console.log` statement to send the object and string literal to the console as separate arguments, since trying to concatenate them [produces incorrect output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69474477/328193).)

(As an aside, there's also another error in your browser's console that's [easily corrected](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30968113/328193).)

Comment: but i only want to see the value of races and not the one of the id in the console.log

Comment: I want that in e2 it only shows me the value of the degree and not the id, for example "attorney", and no other data.

Comment: I need that in e2 I only extract the item.carrera

Comment: how would it look in the code?

Comment: It is that the way I leave it in e2 is bringing the entire object, and I only need to capture the value of itam.carrera and I have not been able to do it.

Comment: Example: when I select a record it appears in the console.log '{label: "ABOGADA(O)", value: "1"}
"Selected" ',
It brings the whole object but what I need is that it only show me "ABOGADA(O)"

Comment: It had not worked for me but it already worked with the option that he gave me